# CMD compare folders and write report on new files and smaller files

Tags: command-line, cmd, compare

I would like to write a batch file that compares two folders in 2 ways:

1. compare just the names and write into a folder only names of files that exist in the first folder but don't exist in the second folder - I have been trying both comp and writing file names to a text file and using fc, but both show extra information that I don't need. I need just the names of the removed files.
2. compare the sizes of the files that have the same file names in both folders and give a list of only files that are smaller by more than 5% in the second folder, compared to the first one. Again, I need just the names of these files (and possibly the percentage difference, if possible).

I would like results of both to be written to a txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's final version...

```
@ECHO OFF 

SETLOCAL

SET "dir1=P:\week3"
SET "dir2=P:\week4"

SET "report1=P:\Test\removed.txt"
SET "report2=P:\Test\existinfirstnotsecond.txt"
SET "report3=P:\Test\smallerinsecond.txt"
SET "report4=P:\Test\fullreport.txt" 

DEL "%report1%" 2>NUL >nul
DEL "%report2%" 2>NUL >nul
DEL "%report3%" 2>NUL >nul
DEL "%report4%" 2>NUL >nul

FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /a-d "%dir2%\*"') DO (
IF NOT EXIST "%dir1%\%%i" (
    >> "%report1%" ECHO %%i
)
)

FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /a-d "%dir1%\*"') DO (
IF EXIST "%dir2%\%%i" (
    FOR %%q IN ("%dir1%\%%i") DO (
        FOR %%s IN ("%dir2%\%%i") DO (
            CALL :sizes %%~zq %%~zs %%i
        )
    )
) ELSE (
    >> "%report2%" ECHO %%i
)
)

ECHO Old Folder is: %dir1% > "%report4%"
ECHO New Folder is: %dir2% >> "%report4%"
ECHO. >> "%report4%"
ECHO New files are: >> "%report4%"
TYPE "%report1%" >> "%report4%"
ECHO. >> "%report4%"
ECHO Removed files are: >> "%report4%"
TYPE "%report2%" >> "%report4%"
ECHO. >> "%report4%"
ECHO Files smaller by over 5%% are: >> "%report4%"
TYPE "%report3%" >> "%report4%"

START notepad "%report4%"

GOTO :EOF
::^^^^^:: This extra line inserted...PW

:sizes
SET siz1=%1
SET siz2=%2
SET name=%3

:simplify
IF [%siz1:~5%] NEQ [] (
IF [%siz2:~5%] NEQ [] (
    SET siz1=%siz1:~0,-1%
    SET siz2=%siz2:~0,-1%
    GOTO :simplify
)
)

SET /a diff=10000-(10000*%siz2%/%siz1%)

IF %diff% LSS 500 GOTO :EOF
SET diff=00%diff%
SET diff=%diff:~-4,2%.%diff:~-2% 

:report
>> "%report3%" ECHO %diff%%% %name%

GOTO :EOF
```

Only adjustment needed is to add the extra `GOTO :EOF` line as indicated, otherwise execution of the batch will pass straight through to the `:sizes` routine and probably render a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "dir1=."
SET "dir2=.\e"
SET "report1=u:\existinfirstnotsecond.txt"
SET "report2=u:\smallerinsecond.txt"
DEL "%report1%" 2>NUL >nul
DEL "%report2%" 2>NUL >nul
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /a-d "%dir1%\*"') DO (
 IF EXIST "%dir2%\%%i" (
  FOR %%q IN ("%dir1%\%%i") DO FOR %%s IN ("%dir2%\%%i") DO (
   CALL :sizes %%~zq %%~zs "%%i"
   )
 ) ELSE (
 >>"%report1%" ECHO %%i
 )
)

GOTO :EOF

:sizes
IF %2 GEQ %1 GOTO :EOF
IF %2 equ 0 SET "diff= LOTS"&GOTO report
SET /a diff=%1 - %2
SET /a diff=%diff%*10000/%1
IF %diff% LSS 500 GOTO :EOF
SET diff= %diff%
SET diff=%diff:~-4,2%.%diff:~-2%
:report
>>"%report2%" ECHO %diff%%% %~3
GOTO :eof
```

This should produce the results you want. You just need to replace the settings of `dir1,dir2,report1` and `report2`

If the first filename exists in the second directory, send the sizes of both and the filename to the procedure `:sizes`, otherwise, write the name of the file found but missing in the second dir to `report1`

If the size of the first is greater than or equal to the size of the second, don't report it, if the second file has length 0, then the %diff is infinite, otherwise calculate the difference, multiply it by 10000 and divide the result by the size of the first file. Result is 0..10000; 500 means 5%, if less than 5% ignore it, otherwise add a leading space, insert a dot and report the difference.

The only problem may arise if the files are >200K, where the maths would need to be a little more sophisticated (batch is limited to 32-bit signed integers)

---

Edit 20130625-1958Z - For..%%i /%%q/%%s loops replaced original to fix problem with missing directoryname.

---

Edit 20130626-1601Z - replacement `SIZES` routine for longer files

```
:sizes
:: establish the file sizes
SET siz1=%1&SET siz2=%2
:szloop
:: Size of file 1 insanely less than size of file 2 ?
IF NOT DEFINED siz1 GOTO :EOF 
:: Size of file 2 insanely less than size of file 1 ?
IF NOT DEFINED siz2 SET "diff= LOTS"&GOTO report
:: keep peeling the last digit from the sizes until
:: neither is more than 5 digits long
IF NOT %siz1:~5%%siz2:~5%x==x SET siz1=%siz1:~0,-1%&SET siz2=%siz2:~0,-1%&GOTO szloop
:: Now use SIZ1 and SIZ2
IF %siz2% GEQ %siz1% GOTO :EOF
IF %siz2% equ 0 SET "diff= LOTS"&GOTO report
SET /a diff=siz1 - siz2
SET /a diff=%diff%*10000/siz1
IF %diff% LSS 500 GOTO :EOF
SET diff= %diff%
SET diff=%diff:~-4,2%.%diff:~-2%
:report
>>"%report2%" ECHO %diff%%% %~3
GOTO :eof
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I've just tested it on my files and it works great for the first report but in the secodn, it would be great if it gave me the names of the files that were compared. I know I need to add the filename here: >>"%report2%" ECHO %diff%%% %~3 , but not sure what to write...

Comment: Not really sure what changes you need. The line currently being output should show lines like `"10.67% filename"` - it does for me. The filenames are the same in both directories; you know what those directorynames are - and the report will only appear if the file in the second is less than 95% of the size of the file in the first. If you want the full filenames, then in place of `%~3` use `%dir1%\%~3` or `%dir2%\%~3` or both. If you wish, after the label `:sizes`, put a line `ECHO %*` to show the parameters delivered to the routine, which are then available as `%1, %2 and %3` the `~` dequotes

Comment: I now can see what the issue is. The parameters don't work for me. Nothing shows for param 1, and for 2 and 3, it's the size of file in dir2 and name of file respectively. that's why also, the percent value is not calculated right (as only one size value is parsed). Do you know what the issue might be?

Comment: OK - fixed that. Problem was that I tested with a current directory of `DIR1` so the file in `dir1` existed. If you run from another directory, the original code would try to find the filesize of `".\%%i"` which in all probability wouldn't exist - hence returning nothing...

Comment: Thank you. It works great! As you said it works for smaller files. Do you have any tips for larger files?

Comment: I have modified the batch - to show the report in a single file and open that file at the end but the file opens each time the file loops. How can I exit this loop? `GOTO :fullreport

:fullreport
ECHO Old Folder is: %dir1% > "%report4%"
ECHO New Folder is: %dir2% >> "%report4%"
ECHO. >> "%report4%"
ECHO New files are: >> "%report4%"
TYPE "%report1%" >> "%report4%"
ECHO. >> "%report4%"
ECHO Removed files are: >> "%report4%"
TYPE "%report2%" >> "%report4%"
ECHO. >> "%report4%"
ECHO Files smaller by over 5%% are: >> "%report4%"
TYPE "%report3%" >> "%report4%"

START notepad "%report4%"`

Comment: New `:sizes` routine to deal with longer files. If the files are 300,004,762 and 284,999,999 bytes for instance, each has the same number of digits lopped from the right until both are <100,000, so the calculation is performed on 30,000 vs 28,499. The routine to do the 5% thing is then performed on the environment variables craeted, not the routine's parameters.

Comment: The modifications you've made don't form a loop. Evidently, you are creating a new report file, then concatenating them with some header info. The lines you've posted should simply be inserted after the last line containing only a single closing-parenthesis (just above the `GOTO :EOF` before the `:sizes` label) If it's placed there, you don't need the `:fullreport` label or its `GOTO`. Batch simply charges right on through labels until it reaches a `GOTO`, batch-program-name or end-of-file.